# Using the pipe operator with functions, but no arguments

Tags: elixir

Elixir lets me write this:

```
"Elixir rocks" |> String.upcase() |> String.split()
```

And I can introduce a function to combine the upcasing and the split:

```
upcase_split = fn (data) -> data |> String.upcase() |> String.split() end
"Elixir rocks" |> upcase_split()
```

Or

```
upcase_split_shorter = &(&1 |> String.upcase() |> String.split())
"Elixir rocks" |> upcase_split_shorter()
```

Is there a way to do this point-free? That is, without having to give a name to that first argument that I need to pass through the whole way?

This doesn't work:

```
nope = String.upcase() |> String.split()
```

but I was hoping there was something along those lines that might?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous functions are called differently than regular module functions. It's better to define your function in a module and call it from there but if you insist on using an anonymous function, you have to use the dot to call it. Like `fun.()`:

```elixir
"Elixir rocks" |> (&(&1 |> String.upcase() |> String.split())).()
```

or simply:

```elixir
upcase_split_shorter = &(&1 |> String.upcase() |> String.split())
"Elixir rocks" |> upcase_split_shorter.()
```

---

While Elixir doesn't officially support [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), you can take a look at some packages and other resources that implement it:

- Package: [Quark](https://github.com/expede/quark)
- Package: [Elixir-Currying](https://github.com/Qqwy/elixir_currying)
- Package: [Kare](https://github.com/yosriady/kare)
- Forum Discussion: [Currying in Elixir](https://elixirforum.com/t/currying-elixir-library-to-add-currying-capability-to-all-your-elixir-functions/1035)
- Blog Post: [Create Currying Functions in Elixir](https://medium.com/@alexander.s.boring/creating-curried-functions-in-elixir-89bb30de8142)
- Blog Post: [Function Currying in Elixir](http://blog.patrikstorm.com/function-currying-in-elixir)